# Is Om namah shivaya mantra in Atharva Veda , SamaVeda or RigVeda?

Tags: vedas, shiva, mantras, rig-veda, atharva-veda

If Om Namah Shivaya given in AtharvaVeda, SamaVeda or Rig Veda then please share the verse.

Comment: @Pandey you can add your answer there too.